# UpdateModel raise exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a strong typed view model and a MetaData partial class which has annotation attributes on required fields and field type.  The Create.aspx view page has a form when submitted will execute Create method in the controller. When the user submit the form without all the required fields entered, upon reaching UpdateModel() line an exception is thrown.  However, none of the error messages specified in the annotated fields is shown.  Instead, the execution iterate through the RuleViolation() and landed at the most generic exception message.  Thus, the user does not know that some required fields are not entered.  If I define the checking if empty of required fields in the RuleVilolation() method then it is not DRY.  Does anyone know why the error messages are not shown from the MetaClass? Thank you.

```
///Controller method
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Create(string id, [Bind(Prefix = "Transfer")]TransferFormViewModel newTransferViewModel, string cancel)
{
  ....
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
      Transfer newTransfer = new Transfer();

      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        try
          {
            Person person = base.ApplicaitonRepository.GetPerson(intID);
            UpdateModel<Transfer>(newTransfer, "Transfer");
            .....
          }
        catch (Exception ex)
          {
            newTransfer.MiscException = ex;
            HelpersLib.ModelStateHelpers.AddModelErrors(this.ModelState, newTransfer.GetRuleViolations());
          }
      }
   }
   return View(new TransferFormViewModel(base.ApplicaitonRepository, newTransfer));
}

///partial domain objec class
[MetadataType(typeof(TransferMetaData))]
public partial class Transfer
{
  public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations()
  {
    ....
  }
}

///MetaData class
class TransferMetaData
{
[Display(Name="List Type")]
public int ListType { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Notification Date/Time is required."), Display(Name = "Notification Date/Time")]
        public DateTime AddedToListDate { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage="Admit Date/Time is required."), Display(Name="Admit Date/Time")]
...
}
```

Comment: You should consider marking your whole code section as code because like this no one will read it because it is unreadable....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have <%= Html.ValidationSummary() %> somewhere in your view?

What entries are in your ModelState?

Comment: Yes, I have Html.ValidationSummary in the view page, but it just shows the last generic error message since it is the last one that captures any none specific violation in the RuleViolation().  The point is that when under-posting a form the required fields error messages don't show in the summary instead the rule violation message is shown.